# how to call trigger in procedure plsql

Tags: plsql

Here i have created my trigger and it is working. how to call that trigger inside the procedure. please provide any solution for this.

below is my trigger

```
create or replace Trigger emp_trigger
Before update on Required_table 

Begin
  
    delete from log_table;  
    

  insert into log_table(employee_name,phone_number,company_name,location,currency)
  (select employee_name,phone_number,company_name,location,currency 
  from Required_table);
end;
```

here is my procedure code and here i want to call that above trigger code

```
create or replace procedure excercise_one 
is 

cursor test_cur is 
select employee_details.emp_name,employee_details.emp_mobile_no,company.company_name,
location.area,currency.currency
from
employee_details, company, location, currency
where 
employee_details.id = company.emp_no and
company.location = location.country and 
location.location_id = currency.location;

ename employee_details.emp_name%type;
emp_mob Employee_Details.Emp_Mobile_No%type;
cname company.company_name%type;
l_area location.area%type;
cur currency.currency%type;

begin
  

 open test_cur;
  loop
  fetch test_cur into ename,emp_mob,cname,l_area,cur;
  
  if test_cur%Found Then
    
     insert into Required_table values (ename,emp_mob,cname,l_area,cur);
   else
     exit;
  end if;
  end loop;
  close test_cur;



end;
```

Comment: Dear @Karthiga,  triggers are fired based on your trigger declaration. So if you declare your trigger like Before INSERT or UPDATE on Required_table, it will be fired when your procedure inserts records on Required_table. is that answer do you seek ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a trigger in the stored procedure. Triggers run automatically and are executed or fired when some events occur.

For more details, please find the following link
https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/oracle-trigger/

Answer (score 0):

It can not be call a trigger from stored procedure.
But it can be call a stored procedure from a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Your Trigger fires only on Update!

For your Problem.
Write a Procedure to manipulate your logtable.
So you can call ist from a Procedure or a Trigger.

MfG
Ingo